# Ruby on Rails Tutorial - Getting Errors, pulling my hair out

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im following [Michael Hartl's tutorial][1] and did the exercises in Chapter 7, and now have 4 errors that I cant figure out how to fix for the life of me.  When I test the production app manually, the errors dont exist at all.  So I don't know if there is something wrong with my text development or something, but Im at a total loss so I thought I'd post here to see if my total noobness is blinding me...thanks for your help!

**Here's the 4 error messages I'm getting:**

```
Failures:

  1) signup with invalid information after submission 
     Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('title', text: "Sign up") }
       expected css "title" with text "Sign up" to return something
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:38:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) signup with invalid information after submission 
     Failure/Error: it { should have_content('error') }
       expected there to be content "error" in "after submission"
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:39:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) signup after saving the user 
     Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  4) signup after saving the user 
     Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success', text: 'Welcome') }
       expected css "div.alert.alert-success" with text "Welcome" to return something
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:61:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 6.8 seconds
10 examples, 4 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:38 # signup with invalid information after submission 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:39 # signup with invalid information after submission 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:60 # signup after saving the user 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:61 # signup after saving the user
```

**Here's the code on my user_pages_spec.rb:**

```
require 'spec_helper'

    require 'spec_helper'

    describe "User pages" do

      subject { page }

      describe "signup page" do
        before { visit signup_path }

        it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Sign up') }
        it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Sign up')) }
      end

      describe "profile page" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      before { visit user_path(user) }

      it { should have_selector('h1',    text: user.name) }
      it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
    end
    end

      describe "signup" do

        before { visit signup_path }

        let(:submit) { "Create my account" }

        describe "with invalid information" do
          it "should not create a user" do
            expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
          end


            describe "after submission" do
              before { click_button submit }

              it { should have_selector('title', text: "Sign up") }
              it { should have_content('error') }
            end
        end

        describe "with valid information" do
          before do
            fill_in "Name",         with: "Example User"
            fill_in "Email",        with: "user@example.com"
            fill_in "Password",     with: "foobar"
            fill_in "Confirmation", with: "foobar"
          end

          it "should create a user" do
            expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
          end
        end

          describe "after saving the user" do
          before { click_button submit }
          let(:user) { User.find_by_email('user@example.com') }

          it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
          it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success', text: 'Welcome') }
        end
      end


  [1]: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/
```

**Here's the template code for views/users/show.html.erb**

```
<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<div class="row">
  <aside class="span4">
    <section>
      <h1>
        <%= gravatar_for @user %>
        <%= @user.name %>

      </h1>
    </section>
  </aside>
</div>
```

**and then here's the users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

 def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take care to format your posts appropriately with four spaces for code and terminal output. Thanks!

Comment: It's hard to debug this problem without seeing the other code for the application. Could you please put it on GitHub?

Comment: Sure, here's a link to it on Github - https://github.com/nfriend21/sample_app

Comment: Oh and also Ryan, is there a link to somewhere that shows me how I should format my posts?  Sorry bout that mate!

Comment: @nfriend21 Hey friend, whenever you see a Question or Answer box you should see an orange `?` box nearby - clicking on that will open some windows to help you with formatting. You can also try [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: cool....can anyone help me with my problem above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allright y'all,

I dont know if not answering my question was some sort of torturous initiation for noobs in this forum, but after almost 24 hours and a good night sleep, I solved the problem!

After a few G searches, I found that I could be stopping some of the variables from passing through by having "end" in the wrong places.  It turns out there were 2 main areas where I was doing this.  Once I found and fixed those, all the errors went away.

I will now pat myself on the back.  I hope this helps any total noobs who run into this same problem in the future.